# No overload for method '' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with the code in `rec.Speechreconized += rec_Speachrecognized`.

I have been looking for answers in the internet but it just won't work. I hope someone can help me.

```
namespace ai
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        Choices list = new Choice {};

        public Form1()
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            list.Add(new String[] {"Hello", "how are you"});

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));

            try
            {
                rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
                rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized();
                rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            }
            catch{return;}
            s.Speak("Hi, I am Ms M, what can i help you?");

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Say(String h)
        {
            s.Speak(h);
        }

        private EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs> rec_Speachrecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string r = e.Result.Text;


            if(r == "hello")
            {
                Say("hi");
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that `rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized();` should just be `rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized;` - you want to create a delegate from the method, not call it.

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized;`

Comment: `rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized` and not `rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized();`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this line

```
rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized();
```

to

```
rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_Speachrecognized;
```

basically remove the () at the end since the event will pass the params but this way you are calling the method without params

Comment: more accurate it's a `Delegate` not a function

Comment: @styx: In the context of "but this way you are calling the funciton without params" it's not a delegate. (It's a method rather than a function, admittedly...)

Comment: @JonSkeet as usual you are right

Comment: @JonSkeet yeap, function was the first thing that came to mind, was literraly doing some javascript and writing funciton blabla() when i posted this :). Thnx for the correction